# react firebase custom fields authentication create user is not storing the custom fields in firestore database collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import fire from "../config/fire";
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import logo from "./logo.png";

export default class CreateUser extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      pwd: "",
      name: "",
      phoneNo: "",
      address: "",
    };
  }
  login(e) {
    const db = fire.firestore();
    e.preventDefault();
    fire
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.pwd)
      //   .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.pwd)
      .then((u) => {
        // console.log(u.user.uid);
        return db.collection("createdUsers").doc(u.user.uid).set({
          email: this.state.email,
          name: this.state.name,
          phoneNo: this.state.phoneNo,
          address: this.state.address,
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        alert("Successfully Created the user!");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
      });
    this.setState({
      email: "",
      pwd: "",
      name: "",
      phoneNo: "",
      address: "",
    });
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={{ margin: 0, padding: 0, maxWidth: 1366 }}>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <div>
              <Form style={{ width: 300, height: 300, margin: "0 auto" }}>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                  <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="Enter your email"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="Enter your email address"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    value={this.state.email}
                    required
                  />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                  <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    id="pwd"
                    name="pwd"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    value={this.state.pwd}
                    required
                  />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicInput1">
                  <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Name"
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    placeholder="Name"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    value={this.state.name}
                    required
                  />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicInput2">
                  <Form.Label>Phone Number</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Phone Number"
                    id="phoneNo"
                    name="phoneNo"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    value={this.state.phoneNo}
                    required
                  />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicInput3">
                  <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Address"
                    id="address"
                    name="address"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    value={this.state.address}
                    required
                  />
                </Form.Group>

                <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={this.login}>
                  Create User
                </Button>
              </Form>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

In the above code, I have custom fields along with email ID and password, and after creating the user, the values in the custom fields are not getting stored in firestore collection. It is not creating the collection also. React firebase custom fields authentication create user is not storing the custom fields in firestore database collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState({
      email: "",
      pwd: "",
      name: "",
      phoneNo: "",
      address: "",
    });
```

Seems to reload your page and stop the async collection update.

You should reset your state after `db.collection("createdUsers")` completes.

Maybe before `alert("Successfully Created the user!");` (in the final then)